# How to make a Segment created by RANDOM Data Extension as SENDABLE?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I splitted a large DE[non-sendable] into 7 segments.

Now I want to send an email to all these 7 segments, but I notice that though I am able to change the main DE as SENDABLE.

But, I cannot change the segmented ones! Can anyone advise!
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the main DE to Sendable before segmenting. This should solve the problem.

Segmenting a Non Sendable DE would result into Non Sendable segmented data extensions.

I've just tested it myself, segmenting a Sendable DE works fine for this use case.. And in the same way, segmenting a Non Sendable DE results into Non Sendable data extensions..

[image]

Comment: It worked for me..Thank you